# Responding to memory pressure on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, cocoa, memory-management, osx-mavericks

On iOS we receive `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` when memory gets low. Is there a similar construct for OS X applications, especially those that target Mavericks?

I know that OS X has a swap file and is perfectly able to page out memory to flash/disk. But I suppose if applications can make intelligent decisions on which memory to purge, there would be less data to page out, wouldn't it?

Just wondering since [Mavericks' Activity Monitor has a "memory pressure" indicator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107126/what-scale-or-measure-does-mavericks-memory-pressure-adhere-to), is there a way for applications to respond to this situation when it happens.

Comment: I believe this question should _not_ be closed because there is a good and valid answer. The universe of discourse is specifically on OS X and it is clear that the system provides facilities (e.g. `NSDiscardableContent`) for an application to accommodate tight-memory situations without resorting to the paging file.

Comment: Both answers here are very wrong. Back in 2014 we added the correct answer  (Actually, neither of the above is correct. There happens to be a notification, only it's not a notification center type - it's a knote. You can get the notification using kevent() and EVFILT_VM filter (That's how iOS eventually sends you the UI notification - it listens on it - likewise libcache purges when it gets it). Additionally, you can use the undocumented system call vm_pressure_monitor, which will block until pressure is detected (so you use it in another thread).

but it was deleted. Go figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS X doesn't exactly provide a notification. Instead, you use caching and purgeable memory. See [Memory Usage Performance Guidelines: Caching and Purgeable Memory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/CachingandPurgeableMemory.html). There's also [libcache](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/libcache_ref/Reference/reference.html), which is a lower-level library.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such notification on OS X, mainly due to the fact that there's no watchdog that kills processes on OS X when their memory usage is too high.

Comment: I find that a bit surprising, as this is part of most Unix kernels.